# Laravel - why not relative URL's?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been learning Laravel recently and I have seemingly missed a key point: why should *relative* links be avoided?

For example, I have been suggested to use `URL::to()` which outputs the full path of the page passed as a parameter - but why do this when you could just insert a relative link anyway? E.g., putting `URL::to('my/page')` into a `<href>` will just insert `http://www.mywebsite.com/my/page` into the `<href>`; but on my website `href='my/page'` works exactly the same. On my website I have based all relative URL's from the `index.php` file found in the public directory.

Clearly, I'm missing a key point as to why full paths are used.

Comment: Here's why relative URLs are not recommended. Lets say you're on `www.mywebsite.com`. The navigation link has a relative URL of `my/page`. Click on it, and it takes you to `www.mywebsite.com/my/page`. It works, right? But the navigation link is still a relative link. Click on it again, and now you are taken to a nonexistent page at `www.mywebsite.com/my/my/page`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that using `route()` on named routes to be a much better practice. If at one point you decide, for example, that your admin panel shouldn't point to *example.com/admin*, but *example.com/dashboard*, you will have to sift through your entire code to find all references to `Url::to("/admin")`. With named routes, you just have to change the reference in `routes.php`

**Example:**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
```

Now every time you need to provide a link to your admin page, just do this:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin</a>
```

Much better approach, in my opinion.

This is even available in your backend, say in `AdminController.php`

```
// do stuff
return redirect()->route('admin');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

Comment: `route()` is Laravel 5 only, one should add.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't it work in [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers)? `<a href="{{route('example')}}">` seems to work for me?

Comment: Yes, that's in Blade, though. If you want to use it in your backend PHP code, it's L5 only.

Comment: Ahhh...! Makes sense. How do I know if something is Blade **only** from looking at the API?

Comment: @dinsdale No, `route` works in Laravel 4. It's not a Blade only thing. It's a helper function that exists globally in `Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`. Source (the docs): http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: @Pistachio Please fix the L4 note as it does exist in L4. :)

Comment: Thanks Thomas Kim, went by what was said in comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Neither absolute nor relative links should be used - it's advisable to use named routes like so:

```
Route::get('my/page', ['as' => 'myPage', function () {
    // return something
}]);
```

or

```
Route::get('my/page', 'FooController@showPage')->name('myPage');
```

Then, generate links to pages using `URL::route()` method (aliased as `route()` in L5), which is available in Blade as well as in your backend code.

That way, you can change the path to your routes at any time without having to worry about breaking links anywhere in your application.